# Редирект вcех поддоменов на http, а основного домена — на https

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

Есть домен и поддомен:
site.com
control.site.com

Оба доступны по обоим протоколам: и http и https. Никаких перенаправлений (пока) нет.

Как домен, так и поддомен смотрят в одну папку.
В htaccess нужно настроить редирект с `http://site.com` на `https://site.com/`
а для поддомена с `https://control.site.com` на `http://control.site.com/`

Comment: нет, ничего не пропущено, мне нужно для подддомена перенаправлять  на http а не на https как сейчас

Comment: мне нужно осуществить редирект для домена с http на https, а для поддомена c https на http.

Comment: да, они доступны по двум протоколам, сайт использует фреймворк, и никаких больше редиректов нету

Comment: я перенёс всю существенную информацию из комментариев в ответ и удалил свои комментарии. предлагаю вам сделать то же самое, чтобы не создавать затруднений другим пользователям: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/189

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @SergiyDudik Добрый день. Аналогичная проблема. Все как у вас. Удалось решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементарно:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://site.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^control\.site\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://control.site.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Оно то все прекрасно, но у меня пишет too many redirects

Comment: @SergiyDudik Сложно сказать в чём дело. На тестовом *XAMPP* этот код работает правильно.

Comment: если закомментировать строку RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off, то редиректов нету, но не работает переадресация на https

Comment: @SergiyDudik Не могу повторить. Может, где-то в потрохах сайта редирект происходит? Попробуйте для начала на пустом каталоге, потом понемногу добавляйте CMS и её содержимое.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]